# scraping json source (no API available)

Tags: json, parsing, web-scraping, zapier, make.com

**How can I scrape this json data into a table/ csv/ text (not picky)?**

I wish to parse this data into an Integromat Scenario (similar to IFTTT/ Zapier), where it will be stored in a table that I can use for the subsequent stages of my Scenario. I'm struggling with the very first step where I pull this data from the source of this website. There is no json API call for this data as far as I can tell.

The website is: https://www.coingecko.com/

[image]

Comment: I also couldn't find any relevant APIs from CoinGecko API V3. I suggest testing out APIFY which can scrape website data, and is also integrated with Zapier. I haven't tried out APIFY myself, so I am not sure to what extent the website can be scraped. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an http module to pull the html into Integromat then filter the data (maybe with regex?) and use the JSON parser module.